# Where the captcha code is located in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I want to display captcha on the same page under the contact form. But I can't able to find where it is located in Shopify liquid code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with liquid code editing, you could try below solution.

https://community.shopify.com/c/Shopify-Design/Adding-Google-reCaptcha-v3-to-the-Shopify-contact-form/td-p/467787

If you are not familiar with editing code, you will have to use an app from shopify app store.